# Any dis advantages of having pthread_mutex_t and pthread_cond_t as class member static variables?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Any dis advantages of having  pthread_mutex_t and pthread_cond_t as class member static variables?

```
 class myclass {
        public:
          static void*  sometrdfn(void*);
          static std::string newVal;
          static  a_namespace::someclass* ptr;
          static pthread_mutex_t lock;
          static pthread_cond_t cond;
    };

std::string myclass::newVal = " Text";
a_namespace::someclass* myclass::ptr = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t myclass::lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t myclass::cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


    void* myclass::sometrdfn(void* This) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
```

I am facing no issues here and everything worksfine so far, but I fear I may end up with some problems? Could somebody evaluate this and suggest me some value modifications if any? since I am new to multi threading I would appreciate a detailed and vivid answer. Thanks :)

Comment: To review working code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

No problem here. Every instance of `myclass` share the same mutexes (lock and cond). So, every time an instance calls sometrdfn, it looks the current mutex state that is shared to all instances which is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the `lock` with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` and the `cond` with `PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER`. But if you really can, you should use `std::mutex` and `std::conditional_variable`.

Comment: @wix, sorry I missed to add the initialization. Now I have edited. Thanks.